Casting enum variant data pointers to enum pointers in Rust
The background:
I've encountered a situation where I have two tree datastructures with different internal and leaf node types. I want to maintain a vector which holds pointers to the leaves using a Vec<PointInTrees> with the following defition:
enum PointInTrees{
    InTreeA(*mut TreeNodeA),
    InTreeB(*mut TreeNodeB),
}

where the following enums are used by either tree to represent leaf and internal nodes:
enum TreeNodeA{
    Internal(W)
    Leaf(X)
}
enum TreeNodeB{
    Internal(Y)
    Leaf(Z)

I'd prefer if PointInTrees's variants instead pointed to X's and Z's but I need to be able to use methods on the TreeNode types sometimes. This led me to wondering if it's possible to cast pointers to enum data to pointers to the enum itself - for example, I'd rather not constantly be pattern matching the TreeNodeAs in my Vec when I know they are all leaves.
Example of desired behaviour
After some messing about, I realised I can cast in the way I want using the following example which does pointer arithmetic to subtract the discriminant. However, this would be very unwieldy and error prone to use in practise.
use std::mem;
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum Message{
    Msg(String),
    OtherMsg(String),
}
fn main() {
    let discriminant_offset = mem::size_of::<isize>();
    println!("Discriminant offset:\t\t {:?}", discriminant_offset);
    let message_pointer: *mut Message = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Message::Msg("Hello".into())));
    let other_message_pointer: *mut Message = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Message::OtherMsg("Hi".into())));
    // Casting a String pointer to Message pointer for the Msg variant
    if let Message::Msg(msg_string) = unsafe{&mut *message_pointer}{
        let string_pointer: *mut String = msg_string;
        let extracted_message_pointer: *mut Message = unsafe{(string_pointer as *mut u8).sub(discriminant_offset) as *mut Message};
        println!("Initial pointer:\t\t {:?}, {:?}", message_pointer, unsafe{&*message_pointer});
        println!("string pointer:\t\t\t {:?}, {:?}", string_pointer, unsafe{&*string_pointer} );
        println!("extracted msg_pointer:\t\t {:?}, {:?}",extracted_message_pointer, unsafe{&*extracted_message_pointer});
    }
    println!();
    // Casting a String pointer to Message pointer for the OtherMsg variant
    if let Message::OtherMsg(other_msg_string) = unsafe{&mut *other_message_pointer}{
        let other_string_pointer: *mut String = other_msg_string;
        let extracted_other_message: *mut Message = unsafe{(other_string_pointer as *mut u8).sub(discriminant_offset) as *mut Message};
        println!("Initial other pointer:\t\t {:?}, {:?}", other_message_pointer, unsafe{&*other_message_pointer});
        println!("other string pointer:\t\t {:?}, {:?}", other_string_pointer, unsafe{&*other_string_pointer} );
        println!("extracted other_msg_pointer:\t {:?}, {:?}", extracted_other_message, unsafe{&*extracted_other_message});
    }
}

My question is how to make this robust and ergonomic and is there something already out there for doing this? Otherwise, I'm thinking about writing a macro which implements From for each possible variant pointer type for a given Enum.
I understand the compiler is free to use discriminant sizes smaller than an isize if it wants so I would need some way of reliably getting the size of the discriminant at compile time.

With the unstable offset_of_enum feature, you could use the core::mem::offset_of macro to do e.g. ptr_to_x.byte_sub(offset_of!(TreeNodeA, Leaf.0)), however ptr_to_x would have to have been derived from a pointer to TreeNodeA in order for this to be sound.

You probably shouldn't do this. It would be better to just move the methods you need to the X and Z types. Then delegate from TreeNode::method to X/Z::method

There are a few aspects of your goal that need pointing out
Provenance
In rough terms, what you're trying to do is currently allowed. A pointer to a sub-object is allowed, by the rules documented on pointer add/sub and the like, to point outside that sub-object so long as it is within the same "allocated object". Which in the case of an enum variant holding the pointed-to value certainly would be.
However, if Rust adopts strict provenance, then this would not be allowed. Under strict provenance, such a pointer and any pointer derived from it can only access the memory for which that pointer has provenance (i.e. just the leaf type). The documentation in std::ptr has much more details on strict provenance, but as it stands it is still an experimental policy. My understanding is that the Rust team would like strict provenance, or at least a stricter version than it currently has, but its not clear to me when that would happen (if anyone has links to current plans that'd be appreciated).
Layout
The default Rust layout of fields in all datatypes (which includes enum discriminant and variant payloads) is unspecified, so you are currently relying on unspecified behavior and thus your assumptions could be wrong when compiling it later. Unlikely, but technicalities are important.
Fortunately, you just need a #[repr(C)] on the enum to give it a specified layout, and even better to also specify the size of the discriminant:
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
#[repr(C, u64)]
enum Message{
    Msg(String),
    OtherMsg(String),
}

That way the layout is guaranteed to be discriminant first and then variant data (with padding in between if needed to satisfy alignment). Then you know that there will always be a fixed offset. See type layout for more info.
The Offset
As for actually deducing the value of the discriminant_offset in a future-proof way, I don't know. @eggyal in the comments suggests an improvement to offset_of! may make this fairly trivial in the future. But right now, what you have std::mem::size_of should be okay (though I would suggest a non-variable size one like u64) but only if and only if the discriminant size matches the alignment of the variant data.
So help ensure that, I would suggest adding some static asserts to generate a compiler error if those assumptions change.
const _: () = { assert!(std::mem::size_of::<u64>() >= std::mem::align_of::<String>()); };

The Code

My question is how to make this robust and ergonomic and is there something already out there for doing this?

I'm not aware of any existing crates that do this. You have a lot of code in your post but the casting itself is a single line. You can wrap this up into nice methods:
// a bit silly since the `Message` variants are the same type, but just
// demonstrating what multiple variant types would look like
impl Message {
    pub fn from_msg_ptr(ptr: *const String) -> *const Message {
        ptr.byte_sub(std::mem::size_of::<u64>()).cast()
    }
    pub fn from_msg_ptr_mut(ptr: *mut String) -> *mut Message {
        ptr.byte_sub(std::mem::size_of::<u64>()).cast()
    }
    pub fn from_other_msg_ptr(ptr: *const String) -> *const Message {
        ptr.byte_sub(std::mem::size_of::<u64>()).cast()
    }
    pub fn from_other_msg_ptr_mut(ptr: *mut String) -> *mut Message {
        ptr.byte_sub(std::mem::size_of::<u64>()).cast()
    }
}


Otherwise, I'm thinking about writing a macro which implements From for each possible variant pointer type for a given Enum.

I would not recommend using From conversions for this. A macro would make sense though, certainly if there's a lot of variants.

Overall though, I do not encourage you to do this. You should change your design; "I need to be able to use methods on the TreeNode types sometimes" when "I know they are all leaves" seems like a shortcoming in functionality and/or a failing to encode data invariants in your types properly.

Someone should double-check my reasoning since miri flags using the resulting pointers as UB. I think that's only because stacked borrows (how miri detects it) are more strict than the current rules? I'm unsure though.

Thanks @kmdreko.  #[repr(C, u64)] seems the way to go. You're probably right about not being the best way to encode my data invariants. I'm still quite new to rust. My use case is that the two trees are sampling trees (not binary search trees) with slightly different node types depending on which tree. At each iteration a leaf from one of the trees is sampled at random. I'm reasonably happy with what I have now using pattern matching. This was more of a what if question.

Strict provenance has nothing to do with this, and everything to do with int-to-ptr and ptr-to-int casts.

@ChayimFriedman I thought the strict provenance was covering more than just that, but regardless, do I have it right that pointing to the larger object is allowed in current Rust or is it not? I have not found a good resource for how provenance is thought of currently and the currently documented safety requirements for dereferencing pointers do not mention a provenance requirement - besides what is said in the std::ptr docs in the context of strict provenance. Again miri doesn't like it but its not clear if that it is due to aspirational rules or current rules.

You can satisfy Miri by creating the *const String from a *const Message (playground): else the *const String doesn't have sufficient provenance to access the containing Message.

If the pointer originates from a reference that points to the whole object, this is definitely sound; if it originates from a reference that points to the sub-object, Stacked Borrows rejects this but Tree Borrows accepts this. I believe the intention is to allow this, but it is not clear how to with Stacked Borrows, and so it isn't committed this is allowed. And in general, there is no "SB is stricter than the current rules"; the current rules are undecided, and might as well become SB in the future.
